# Установка Windows Drivers для Visual Studio 2013

Tags: драйвер

Всем привет, не могу решить данную проблему. какой мне wdk и sdk именно качать? Как сделать так что бы в Visual Studio 2013 можно было создать проект Windows Drivers? спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проблема заключается в том что я не знаю как установить Windows Drivers для Visual Studio 2013 на windows 7 x64

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста